# Perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql-server, join, union, aggregate-functions

Can't perform any kind of aggregate function. I have 2 tables with entities and one table which contain transactions for every entity.

```
#qui
        +--------+------------+
        |  idx   | nbn        |
        +--------+------------+
        | 44444  | 152357     |    
        | 55555  | 778852     |
        | 66666  | 776856     |
        +--------+------------+
#zea
        +--------+------------+
        |  idx   | nbn        |
        +--------+------------+
        | 11111  | 159357     |    
        | 22222  | 753852     |
        | 33333  | 745856     |
        +--------+------------+
#trx
        +--------+------------+---------+--------+
        |  idx   | nbn        |trx_amt  |date    |
        +--------+------------+---------+--------+
        | 11111  | 159357     |100      |01-01-16|
        | 22222  | 753852     |200      |04-04-16|
        | 33333  | 745856     |300      |11-05-16|
        +--------+------------+---------+--------+
```

My query:

```
    select 
      date
     ,qui_co = count (case when trx.idx in (select idx from qui) then trx_amt
     ,zea_co = count (case when trx.idx in (select idx from zea) then trx_amt 
end)
    from 
      trx 
        inner join (select idx from qui
                    union 
                    select idx from zea) xxx
        on trx.idx = xxx.idx
group by date
```

Any idea for some other solution ?

Comment: Your first case expression is missing an `end`, and your question is not very clear. Please add desired output, and please, change the sample data to DDL + DML statements so that we can try to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with left joins:

```
select [date], count(q.idx), count(z.idx)
from trx t
left join qui q on t.idx=q.idx
left join zea z on t.idx=z.idx
group by [date]
```